# How to unscrew this light?

Tags: lighting

I have a light like this above my shower. I can't seem to unscrew it and am worried about breaking things if I push too much. My question is: how is this supposed to be unscrewed? I don't see any buttons or switches on the outside that might have to be toggled to unscrew it. Do I unscrew the clear part in the middle? Do I unscrew the outer white plastic ring? The white ring may be a little bit painted to the ceiling in a few small places. Maybe that is the issue? Thanks! Again, just don't want to break it.

[image]

**Update:** I used a screw driver to remove the paint and it came right down. It had to be pried open not unscrewed.

[image]

Comment: what makes you believe that it has to be turned like a light bulb?

Comment: why do you need to remove it?

Comment: @jsotola the light is out inside

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a typical "spring retained" trim that should pull straight down, (white ring and glass together) once you break the paint bond.

However, there are trims (and replacement bulb and trim in one) that look the same but are retained by sprung blades what will retract if you turn counterclockwise. Can't be certain until you try it. Since you've already tried unscrewing without progress, try pulling straight down.

Comment: I pried it open like a paint lid with a screwdriver and it worked perfectly.